# LinQ query, only one record submitted/inserted

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I'm trying to insert only males teachers into the "MaleTeachers" table, but after program is executed I see only one teacher in that table. In addition, I have more then one teacher in the "Stuffs" table, but inserted one is the last that matches "if" criteria. Could you correct this code please. Service implementation:

```
public void AddTeachers()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    DataClasses2DataContext data2 = new DataClasses2DataContext();
    MaleTeacher tchr = new MaleTeacher();

    foreach (var d in data.Stuffs)
    {
        if (d.stuffSex == true && d.stuffJob == "Teacher")
        {
            tchr.teacherName = d.stuffName;
            tchr.teacherAge = d.stuffAge;
            tchr.teacherJob = d.stuffJob;
            tchr.teacherDepartm = "geology";
            data2.MaleTeachers.InsertOnSubmit(tchr);
        }
    }

    data2.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving the `tchr` declaration inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Up is right. Move MaleTeach into the foreach loop. YYou are inserting only the last teacher.

Comment: For claritys sake you could be using data2.MaleTeachers.InsertOnSubmit(New MaleTeacher() { ... } );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you foreach loop should be.

```
  foreach (var d in data.Stuffs)
        {
            if (d.stuffSex == true && d.stuffJob == "Teacher")
            {
                MaleTeacher tchr = new MaleTeacher();
                tchr.teacherName = d.stuffName;
                tchr.teacherAge = d.stuffAge;
                tchr.teacherJob = d.stuffJob;
                tchr.teacherDepartm = "geology";
                data2.MaleTeachers.InsertOnSubmit(tchr);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating only one intance and then modifying it again and again... instead you should create a different `MaleTeacher` instance on every time.

```
MaleTeacher tchr = new MaleTeacher();

foreach (var d in data.Stuffs)
{
    if (d.stuffSex == true && d.stuffJob == "Teacher")
    {
        tchr.teacherName = d.stuffName;
        tchr.teacherAge = d.stuffAge;
        tchr.teacherJob = d.stuffJob;
        tchr.teacherDepartm = "geology";
        data2.MaleTeachers.InsertOnSubmit(tchr);
        tchr = new MaleTeacher();
    }
}
```